# Update v-for When Data Is Added To Array - VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I'm kinda new to VueJS so I was hoping to get some help. I'm currently returning an array of json objects from a PHP file.

Example:

```
<?php
  /*
   Returns an array similar to this:
    [
      {name: 'foo'}, 
      {name: 'bar'}, 
      {name: 'banana'}
    ]
  */

  echo json_encode(array_values($array));
?>
```

And I'm appending this array of objects to an already existing array of objects in Vue:

```
axios.post('http://localhost/get_array.php').then(response => {
  // Append returned array to already existing array
  for (var i = 0; i <= response.data.length - 1; i++) {
    this.existingArray.push(response.data[i])
  }
}).catch(e => {
  console.log("Error")
})
```

Right now I'm appending the data with a for loop but I was wondering if VueJS has an in-built function that does this automatically without having to use the for loop?

Comment: See [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [Reactivity in depth on Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html).

Comment: I tried using `concat()` to merge the arrays but it wouldn't update the view where I was rendering them. I also tried `Vue.set()` but also couldn't get it to work, that's why I had to resort back to the for loop. @Nit

Comment: How were you using `concat`?

Comment: I was just doing this: `this.existingArray.concat(response.data)`. Thanks everyone, I got it working with `concat` now and it's much easier than the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **concat** which returns a new concatenated array:

```
axios.post('http://localhost/get_array.php')
  .then(response => {
    this.existingArray = this.existingArray.concat(response.data)
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log("Error")
  })
```

Updating *existingArray* with the result of calling **concat** with the *response data* should trigger the update.